# Compiler warnings with BlocksKit 1.8.1 / Xcode 4.5 / iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I'm getting warnings when using BlocksKit 1.8.1 in Xcode 4.5 with an iOS project.

The warning is:

[image]

And the details are:

> GenerateDSYMFile
>   /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-epvlodroaifdsbacdbbxnlhuptrh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app.dSYM
>   /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-epvlodroaifdsbacdbbxnlhuptrh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/AppName
>       cd /Users/john/Documents/AppName_iphone
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
>   /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-epvlodroaifdsbacdbbxnlhuptrh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/AppName
>   -o /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-epvlodroaifdsbacdbbxnlhuptrh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app.dSYM

When compiling with device target.

When compiling with the simulator as target, the warnings are a bit different:

[image]

I've followed the instructions on the Git page:

- Download a release of BlocksKit.
- Move libBlocksKit.a and Headers to your project's folder, preferably a subfolder like "Vendor".
- In "Build Phases", Drag libBlocksKit.a into your target's "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase.
- In the build settings of your target or project, change "Other Linker Flags" to -ObjC -all_load. Make sure your app is linked with CoreGraphics, Foundation, MessageUI, and UIKit.
- Change (or add) to "Header Search Paths" the relative path to BlocksKit's headers, like $(SRCROOT)/Vendor/Headers.
- Insert #import ` in your project's prefix header.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is a bug that will be fixed in the next release of BlocksKit:

https://github.com/pandamonia/BlocksKit/issues/108

Answer (score 1):

I have the same warnings and couldn't find the reason but have found a temporary solution.

**Maybe related:**

There seem to be more problems with linking in BlocksKit 1.8.1: My app compiles and works correctly for development builds (although these warnings are shown). However, when I build an archive for Ad Hoc deployment, libBlocksKit is apparently *not* linked, as the app crashes when one of the BlocksKit methods is invoked with the following crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3b2783e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a2d195e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3b27bdbc +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3b27a648 ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3b1d2204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
```

For all build configurations my other linker flags are set to `-ObjC`. (I dropped `-all_load` because this leads to a "duplicate symbols" with an AdMob library I'm using.)

**Temporary solution:**

I switched back to an older branch of BlocksKit:
https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit
and use linker flags `-ObjC`.
This branch is deprecated but works for me without any of the above warnings for all build configurations.